# Speech app for Ebook Apps

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, kindle

I actually want to develop an Android app, which can be used to read aloud the words from apps like Kindle, nook, etc. Is there any possible way?
I don't think this is possible, but my client somehow wants this to be done!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in text to speech support in Android 1.6 or higher. See http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html for more details.